# What is i/o port , i/o port address? Is that address a part of RAM?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device

What is i/o port , i/o port address?  When a driver wants to communicate with hardware, for example the parallel port (0x378). That port address(0x378) is RAM address or something else?

Comment: what's the context of those terms? `i/o` is generally input/output and can refer to a variety of concepts

Comment: when a driver wants to communicate with hardware. example parallel port (0x378). that port address(0x378) is RAM address or something else?

Comment: http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch08.html#t2

Answer (score 13):

This ultimately depends on the architecture of the system.

x86 processors and the 8080 (and ultimately 8008) from which they descend use a scheme called `I/O mapping` where a special control signal from the processor indicates that an access is to an I/O port rather than a regular memory location.  A corresponding special instruction must be used for such access.

Many other processors - especially the ARM cores so widespread in mobile and embedded devices today - follow from a different design tradition in which I/O ports are `memory mapped` within the same unified address space as ordinary memory.  This means that they appear as regular memory locations (in a special reserved address region) and are accessed with fairly normal instructions.  One caveat however is that sometimes only specific width access is permitted - for example a 32-bit embedded ARM chip may require that a particular port be accessed using a 16-bit memory access instructions, even though a full 32-bit bus word is reserved for it.

Ultimately the information about a specific processor is found in its Data Sheet or Programmer's Manual.  Systems with busses connecting off-chip peripherals - especially bridged busses - may add additional constraints.

Comment: Is the 'control signal' you mention a hardware line that goes to both the IO devices and the memory controller to indicate "Hey, I am / am not talking to memory"?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  It is an output of the processor, and might go directly to a peripheral chip with a spare enable input, or else be factored into address decoding (and possibly wait-state-generating) logic.

Comment: I have a question about I/O port address.
the I/O port address is fixed?
for example, Is usb port's I/O port address always started at some fixed addresses？
if it is not, how can I know the I/O port address of some devices?

Answer (score 3):

Each I/O device connected to your computer is mapped to a unique I/O (Input/Output) address. These addresses are assigned to every I/O port on your computer, including `USB`, `Firewire`, `Ethernet`, `VGA` etc. In your computer there are `65,535` ports that are numbered from `0000h` to `FFFFh`.

I/O addresses are controlled by the computer's **motherboard**, they do not use up any system memory, or RAM. Having a unique address assigned to each port allows your computer to easily recognize and locate devices attached to your computer. Whether it is a keyboard, mouse, monitor, printer, or any other device, the computer can locate it by its I/O address.

Comment: There are probably exactly zero USB and Firewire controllers that are attached to I/O ports. Maybe you can find vintage Ethernet hardware with I/O ports, maybe graphics cards still have legacy I/O port interfaces, I don't know. I/O ports (a x86 specific thing in any case) are really just used for legacy devices that were already around before PCI took off.

Answer (score 1):

The two ways of connecting a peripheral to cpu is 1)through a dedicated I/O bus(port mapped I/O) 2)interfacing to processor via memory controller(Memory mapped I/O).

port mapped I/O devices are directly addressed by processor and need special instructions to achieve it.

Memory mapped I/O needs address translation ie.., Some of the physical addresses are dedicated to I/O. To read or write from these devices we can just use instructions generally as that of reading or writing into RAM locations.In brief we are completely abstracted from directly accessing the device status and control registers (and other registers if any) via memory controller.

That is what ioremap() function in kernel exactly does for the above implementation to happen ie.., mapping device address region into process's virtual address space.
The memory ,devices and cpu are connected to primary address bus.when bus sees certain addresses the addressing decoding circuitry knows that they are not the memory addresses but are generated to access a I/O device.

Besides note that port mapped devices can be accessed from user and kernel mode but memory mapped devices are mapped from kernel space only.

In nut shell the answer for the question you asked is -the address 0x378 will be a reserved physical ram address if it were to be a memory mapped one.

Try cat /proc/iomem if the address not here then it is a port mapped one for sure.
hope this clarifies you

@Gopikrishnaraju